# Access list of object array with alias in jpa

Tags: jpa

i have written a native query in jpa which fetch list of object array

```
   list = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select emp.card Card,emp.code Code,emp.emp_name EmpName,ln.BAL Balance, ln.cum_intr CumIntr, ln.install Install,ln.install_no InstallNo, "
                        + " led.BAL ledgBAL,led.cum_intr ledgCum,led.install ledgInstall,led.install_no ledgInstallNo "
                        + " from LOANS ln "
                        + " inner join "
                        + " LOAN_LEDGER led "
                        + " on (led.EMPLOYEES_ID =  ln.EMPLOYEES_ID and ln.LOAN_UID= led.LOAN_UID and (ln.bal!= led.BAL or ln.cum_intr!= led.cum_intr or ln.INSTALL != led.INSTALL )) "
                        + " inner join EMPLOYEES emp "
                        + " on ln.employees_id = emp.id "
                        + "  where led.ledger_month in  "
                        + " ( 201312  )").getResultList();
```

I assigned alias for each field.this is my code to access this object array.

```
   Iterator it = list.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {

        Object[] result = (Object[]) it.next();

        System.err.println("Result Arrayyyyy   "+result[0]);
    }
```

Now i want to access this result array using alias . How can I do it?

Comment: You can't do it. Object[] only have an index to reference the value

Comment: Well you can do it if you use Tuple as the result class, assuming your JPA provider supports Tuple as a result class